# Walking to someone

Tags: meaning, word-choice, difference, phrase-usage, phrase-request

Id like to know if these various sentences about walking to someone mean the same thing

1. I’m walking up to her.
2. I’m walking towards her.
3. Im walking to her.

I’d appreciate knowing other ways to say what I mean

Comment: Oh read that again now

Comment: More ways than that?

Answer (score 0):

They all have similar meanings.  "Towards" indicates a direction, whereas "To" suggests a destination. You can be walking towards the moon, but you can't walk to the moon. Moreover, "Walking up to her" implies that you are aiming to come close to the person.

The verb "approach" can be used with similar meaning (though it doesn't imply "walking")

> I'm approaching her.

While all these are grammatically correct, actual situations in which you would want to say any such phrase would be rare.  You appear to be talking to a third person who can't see you, but needs to know exactly where you are walking.  It could be a phone call, but it seems unlikely.

Comment: "Walking up to her" implies that you are aiming to come close to the person, while "towards", as James says, could just mean "in her direction".

Comment: thanks, incorporated your suggestion.